# Is there a plane filling function calculator online?

Tags: plane-curves, fractals, online-resources

I recently read about the "Hilbert Curve" and found it very interesting. Does anyone know of a place online where I could extrapolate different shapes and explore this field of mathematics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.dangries.com/Flash/FractalMakerExp/FractalMaker_exp.html) is a fairly good L-system fractal generator, it doesn't specialize in space filling curves, but you can make space-filling curves with it.